# Difference between "as well as" and "in addition to"

Tags: conjunctions

> Designers can use this software to create original graphics and artwork ------- to manipulate and alter digital photography.

1. as well as
2. rather
3. along with
4. in addition.

I can immediately remove `rather` from the options.

I can't distinguish the sentences where `as well as` and `in addition` is used respectively.

> Designers can use this software to create original graphics and artwork as well as to manipulate and alter digital photography.

> Designers can use this software to create original graphics and artwork in addition to manipulate and alter digital photography.

I think that both sentences make sense.

[synonyms of as well as](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/as%20well%20as) shows us that one of synonyms of `as well as` can be `in addition to` . I think both option1,3 can be assumed as correct answers.

BTW `along with` also may make sense in the sentence.

Can anyone explain me the logics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiom is "in addition to," as you put in the title.

They offered instead a different idiom "in addition," which does not work as a conjunction.  It would be fine in the sentence

> Designers can use this software to create original graphics and artwork and, in addition, to manipulate and alter digital photography.

To use "in addition to," you can not use the "to" as part of the idiom AND to create an infinitive, so you would need something like this, in order to have a noun for parallelism.

> Designers can use this software to create original graphics and artwork in addition to manipulating and altering digital photography.